# VBA to keep certain columns and remove all others

Tags: excel, vba

As topic says I have a vba code which does the job: remove all columns of sheet "incidents" and keep only the columns with names "Status", "Name" and "Age"

But for some reason, after a few thousand rows, it does not work properly and removes the data/cells of that columns that is keeping , and also works quite slow.

There is any other way to do this? More efective? At least to not remove any cell of that columns which must remain in the sheet.

Thanks in advance (code below).

```
Sub Cleanup_report2()
    Dim currentColumn As Integer
    Dim columnHeading As String

    For currentColumn = Worksheets("Incidents").UsedRange.Columns.CounT To 1 Step -1

        columnHeading = Worksheets("Incidents).UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value

        'CHECK WHETHER TO KEEP THE COLUMN
        Select Case columnHeading

            Case "Status", "Name", "Age"
                'Do nothing
            Case Else

                If InStr(1, _
                    Worksheets("Incidents").UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value, _
                   "DLP", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then

                     Worksheets("Incidents").Columns(currentColumn).Delete

                End If
        End Select
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: That code only deletes entire columns, not individual cells. (well, the code as posted wouldn't actually run at all, but I assume that's a typo) Also, you appear to be referring to 2 different worksheets?

Comment: `UsedRange` is probably causing the problem.  It's not very reliable at find the end of data - if you delete columns, it may not notice.  This link gives various methods on how to find the last cell containing data: http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/ExcelRanges.htm  After reading Rorys comment - you're looking to clear the contents of a cell rather than deleting the whole column.

Comment: @Rory just one sheet called incidents_data , was a typo .. the code below was an example

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I want to drop the columns which i don't need, giving the ones I need. Just that

Comment: @Gonzalo: could it be that you have merged cells where the data suddenly disappears?

Comment: @Gonzalo: about the performance: could you state how big the sheet is (rows and columns)?  Without that info it's hard to tell what needs optimizing.  But at least investigate the Application.ScreenUpdating setting.

Comment: @Carl Colijn The original sheet has 50 columns and around 50k rows. And from those 50 columns I just need 6 or 7 ... below I said 3 as an example. Anyway, with the code below, if the numbers of rows are bellow 10k it seems to work.. slow.. but works. No cells merged.

Comment: Instead of deleting could you copy what you need to a new sheet? It might be quicker, also turning off calculation before deleting then turning on after might speed it up particularly if it deleting a column at a time.

Answer (score 1):

It should be quicker to only do one delete operation:

```
Sub Cleanup_report2()
    Dim currentColumn         As Integer
    Dim columnHeading         As String
    Dim rDelete               As Excel.Range

    With Worksheets("Incidents_data")

        For currentColumn = .UsedRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1

            columnHeading = .UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value

            'CHECK WHETHER TO KEEP THE COLUMN
            Select Case columnHeading

                Case "Status", "Name", "Age"
                    'Do nothing
                Case Else

                    If InStr(1, columnHeading, "DLP", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
                        If rDelete Is Nothing Then
                            Set rDelete = .UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn)
                        Else
                            Set rDelete = Union(rDelete, .UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn))
                        End If
                    End If
            End Select
        Next
    End With

    If Not rDelete Is Nothing Then rDelete.EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: doesnt help this code, just run it and behaves like the one i copied above. the rows over 4000 just have partial information. But it keeps the correct columns and the code posted above.

Comment: by the way, the "original sheet" has 50 columns and around 50k rows.  And from those 50 columns i need 8 maybe.

Comment: This code only manipulates entire columns. Do you have merged cells in your data?

Comment: No .. it's normal columns with data that are imported from a xml

Comment: What exactly do you mean by partial information? I don't see how the code could partially affect any cells - it either deletes the cells or it doesn't.

Comment: How is "after a few thousand rows" and you are not looping through rows ?

Comment: My apologies,  the issue is when I import from the XML to the sheet.. some data disappear.. I will create another question for that.. something is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my anser... hope this helps...

```
Sub removeColumns()

    Dim rng As Range 'store the range you want to delete
    Dim c 'total count of columns
    Dim i 'an index
    Dim j 'another index
    Dim headName As String 'The text on the header
    Dim Status As String 'This vars is just to get the code cleaner
    Dim Name As String
    Dim Age As String
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Status = "Status"
    Name = "Name"
    Age = "Age"
    Set sht = Sheets("Incidents")

    sht.Activate 'all the work in the sheet "Incidents"
    c = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
    'From A1 to the left at the end, and then store the number
    'of the column, that is, the last column
    j = 0 'initialize the var
    For i = 1 To c 'all the numbers (heres is the columns) from 1 to c
        headName = Cells(1, i).Value
        If (headName <> Status) And (headName <> Name) And (headName <> Age) Then
        'if the header of the column is differente of any of the options
            j = j + 1 ' ini the counter
            If j = 1 Then 'if is the first then
                Set rng = Columns(i)
            Else
                Set rng = Union(rng, Columns(i))
            End If
         End If
    Next i
    rng.Delete 'then brutally erased from leaf
End Sub
```